# Can the encryption option with zip on Linux when used from the command line?

Tags: linux, redhat, compression

Can the encryption option on Info-ZIP be used from the command line? The zip man page says:

> -e
>   --encrypt Encrypt the contents of the zip archive using a password which is entered on the terminal in response to a prompt (this will
>   not be echoed; if standard error is not a tty, zip will exit with an
>   error). The password prompt is repeated to save the user from typing
>   errors.

Is there a way to create zipped files from an unattended script?

Comment: If you really want any level of encryption worth mentioning (zip encryption is trivial to crack) you should use something like `openssl bf -salt -k passphrase -in file.zip -out file.zip.bfe` to encrypt the zip file (this can also be done on the fly by piping. Decryption is as easy as `openssl bf -d -salt -k passphrase -in file.zip.bfe -out file.zip`. Zip doesn't support unzipping from a pipe, so you can't decrypt a zip on the fly with openssl. You can use gzip and tar however, it depends on your needs.

Comment: @ChrisS I guess there is a free OpenSSL client for windows too. The zipped files will be sent to an FTP server to be picked up by a Windows user. The encryption is mainly just to avoid a casual user from accidentally peeking into the file.

Comment: N.b. The zip command on Redhat is copyright Info-ZIP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `-P` will allow you to pass the password on the command line.